# Number of Paths in a Triangle

Tags: algorithm, recursion, dynamic-programming, combinatorics

I recently encountered a much more difficult variation of this problem, but realized I couldn't generate a solution for this very simple case. I searched Stack Overflow but couldn't find a resource that previously answered this.

You are given a triangle ABC, and you must compute the number of paths of certain length that start at and end at 'A'. Say our function f(3) is called, it must return the number of paths of length 3 that start and end at A: 2 (ABA,ACA).

I'm having trouble formulating an elegant solution. Right now, I've written a solution that generates all possible paths, but for larger lengths, the program is just too slow. I know there must be a nice dynamic programming solution that reuses sequences that we've previously computed but I can't quite figure it out. All help greatly appreciated.

My dumb code:

```
def paths(n,sequence):
    t = ['A','B','C']
    if len(sequence) < n:
        for node in set(t) - set(sequence[-1]):
            paths(n,sequence+node)
    else:
        if sequence[0] == 'A' and sequence[-1] == 'A':
            print sequence
```

Comment: Can you give an example with a just slightly bigger triangle?

Comment: Sorry I do not quite understand. If I added another point on the triangle, it would be another cyclic graph, just with 4 points? I will try to solve that now

Comment: I didn't mean 4 points - just whatever you need to do to show a slightly "larger length" as you describe.

Comment: Sorry got it. In the case of n = 21, there are 349526 paths. I just feel there must be some mathematical solution or technique to compute it much more rapidly

Comment: there is, see my answer and try n = 21, it gives 349526 as output

Comment: I see - I didn't understand before. `A B C` stays constant and only `n` changes?

Comment: @SimpleLearner  tell me if anything is uncleared :)  I will edit and make things more clear...also if the path length (i.e.: n) is large, then you may need to change the size of the array and use long long(64bit int) as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let `PA(n)` be the number of paths from A back to A in exactly n steps.
Let `P!A(n)` be the number of paths from B (or C) to A in exactly n steps.

Then:

```
PA(1) = 1
PA(n) = 2 * P!A(n - 1)

P!A(1) = 0
P!A(2) = 1
P!A(n) = P!A(n - 1) + PA(n - 1)
       = P!A(n - 1) + 2 * P!A(n - 2) (for n > 2) (substituting for PA(n-1))
```

We can solve the difference equations for P!A analytically, as we do for Fibonacci, by noting that (-1)^n and 2^n are both solutions of the difference equation, and then finding coefficients a, b such that P!A(n) = a*2^n + b*(-1)^n.

We end up with the equation P!A(n) = 2^n/6 + (-1)^n/3, and PA(n) being 2^(n-1)/3 - 2(-1)^n/3.

This gives us code:

```
def PA(n):
    return (pow(2, n-1) + 2*pow(-1, n-1)) / 3

for n in xrange(1, 30):
    print n, PA(n)
```

Which gives output:

```
1 1
2 0
3 2
4 2
5 6
6 10
7 22
8 42
9 86
10 170
11 342
12 682
13 1366
14 2730
15 5462
16 10922
17 21846
18 43690
19 87382
20 174762
21 349526
22 699050
23 1398102
24 2796202
25 5592406
26 11184810
27 22369622
28 44739242
29 89478486
```

Comment: It took me a while to understand the recurrence relations but I think I get it now. P!A(n) = P!A(n - 1) + PA(n - 1) counts the paths from B to A: 1) P!A(n-1) counts the paths that start at C and end at A of length n-1 but originate from B to get n length.  2) PA(n - 1) counts paths from A to A of length n-1 that originate from B.

Comment: Is this a solution that was immediately obvious to you? If so, are there any problem solving books or problems that helped you?

Comment: @SimpleLearner See the wikipedia page on the fibonacci numbers for almost identical theory (although this series works out a bit nicer because the roots of the quadratic are integers). Also, Sedgewick and Flageolet "Introduction to the analysis of algorithms" covers general techniques for counting discrete structures.

Answer (score 2):

My method is like this:

Define DP(l, end) = # of paths end at `end` and having length `l`
Then DP(l,'A') = DP(l-1, 'B') + DP(l-1,'C'), similar for DP(l,'B') and DP(l,'C')

Then for base case **i.e. l = 1** I check if the end is not 'A', then I return 0, otherwise return 1, so that all bigger states only counts those starts at 'A'

Answer is simply calling DP(n, 'A') where n is the length

Below is a sample code in C++, you can call it with 3 which gives you 2 as answer; call it with 5 which gives you 6 as answer:
**ABCBA, ACBCA, ABABA, ACACA, ABACA, ACABA**

```js
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int dp[500][500], n;

int DP(int l, int end){
 if(l<=0) return 0;
 if(l==1){
  if(end != 'A') return 0;
  return 1;
 }
 if(dp[l][end] != -1) return dp[l][end];
 
 if(end == 'A') return dp[l][end] = DP(l-1, 'B') + DP(l-1, 'C');
 else if(end == 'B') return dp[l][end] = DP(l-1, 'A') + DP(l-1, 'C');
 else return dp[l][end] = DP(l-1, 'A') + DP(l-1, 'B');
}

int main() {
 memset(dp,-1,sizeof(dp));
 scanf("%d", &n);
 
 printf("%d\n", DP(n, 'A'));
 return 0;
}
```

**EDITED**
To answer OP's comment below:

Firstly, DP(dynamic programming) is always about state.

Remember here our state is DP(l,end), represents the # of paths having length `l` and ends at `end`.  So to **implement states** using programming, we usually use **array**, so DP[500][500] is nothing special but the space to store the states DP(l,end) for all possible `l` and `end` (That's why I said if you need a bigger length, change the size of array)

But then you may ask, I understand the first dimension which is for `l`, 500 means l can be as large as 500, **but how about the second dimension? I only need 'A', 'B', 'C', why using 500 then?**

Here is another trick (of C/C++), the `char` type indeed can be used as an `int` type by default, which value is equal to its `ASCII` number. And I do not remember the ASCII table of course, but I know that around 300 will be enough to represent all the ASCII characters, including `A`(65), `B`(66), `C`(67)

So I just declare any size large enough to represent 'A','B','C' in the second dimension (that means actually 100 is more than enough, but I just do not think that much and declare 500 as they are almost the same, in terms of order)

so you asked what DP[3][1] means, it means nothing as the I do not need / calculate the second dimension when it is 1. (Or one can think that the state dp(3,1) does not have any physical meaning in our problem)

In fact, I always using 65, 66, 67.
so DP[3][65] means the # of paths of length 3 and ends at char(65) = 'A'

Comment: I think I understand the approach: the number of paths that end at A is equal to the number of paths of length l-1 that end at B or C and so forth. But what is the dp[500][500] information storing- what would dp[3][1] mean?

Comment: Got it. So just to understand, the DP array is only using dp[x][65], dp[x][66], and dp[x][67] (0<=x<500)? Interesting

Comment: Yes you got it right. so for larger x you need, increase the size of first dimension. And of course you can always change the second dimension as small as 3, and use 0,1,2 to represent A,B,C

Comment: Due to the problem symmetry, it is easy to see that `DP(n, 'B') = DP(n, 'C')`. And so, the formulas can be reduced to `DP(n, 'A') = 2 * DP(n - 1, 'B'); DP(n, 'B') = DP(n - 1, 'A') + DP(n - 1, 'B');`

Answer (score 2):

The trick is not to try to generate all possible sequences. The number of them increases exponentially so the memory required would be too great.

Instead, let `f(n)` be the number of sequences of length `n` beginning and ending `A`, and let `g(n)` be the number of sequences of length `n` beginning with `A` but ending with `B`. To get things started, clearly `f(1) = 1` and `g(1) = 0`. For `n > 1` we have `f(n) = 2g(n - 1)`, because the penultimate letter will be `B` or `C` and there are equal numbers of each. We also have `g(n) = f(n - 1) + g(n - 1)` because if a sequence ends begins `A` and ends `B` the penultimate letter is either `A` or `C`.

These rules allows you to  compute the numbers really quickly using memoization.

Comment: I would also upvote this answer but I do not have the reputation, sorry :(. This explanation was very concise and helped me to understand the other answer.

Comment: @SimpleLearner No worries. I'm glad you found your answer :) There will exist a simple formula for this. Work out f(n) for the first six or so numbers, type them into the Online Encyclopaedia of Integer Sequences and a formula will appear.

Comment: Wow. That is absolutely brilliant. Apparently the equation is (1-x)/(1 - x - 2*x^2). And right there listed is: "closed walks starting and ending at the same vertex of a triangle". Now to figure out how they found that!

Comment: @SimpleLearner "the equation" is the generating function for the recurrence relation for the equation a_{n+2} = a_{n+1} + 2a_{n} with appropriate initial conditions.

Answer (score 2):

You can do better than the dynamic programming/recursion solution others have posted, for the given triangle and more general graphs. Whenever you are trying to compute the number of walks in a (possibly directed) graph, you can express this in terms of the entries of powers of a transfer matrix. Let M be a matrix whose entry m[i][j] is the number of paths of length 1 from vertex i to  vertex j. For a triangle, the transfer matrix is

```
0 1 1
1 0 1.
1 1 0
```

Then M^n is a matrix whose i,j entry is the number of paths of length n from vertex i to vertex j. If A corresponds to vertex 1, you want the 1,1 entry of M^n.

Dynamic programming and recursion for the counts of paths of length n in terms of the paths of length n-1 are equivalent to computing M^n with n multiplications, M * M * M * ... * M, which can be fast enough. However, if you want to compute M^100, instead of doing 100 multiplies, you can use [repeated squaring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring): Compute M, M^2, M^4, M^8, M^16, M^32, M^64, and then M^64 * M^32 * M^4. For larger exponents, the number of multiplies is about c log_2(exponent).

Instead of using that a path of length n is made up of a path of length n-1 and then a step of length 1, this uses that a path of length n is made up of a path of length k and then a path of length n-k.

Answer (score 0):

We can solve this with a `for` loop, although Anonymous described a closed form for it.

```js
function f(n){
  var as = 0, abcs = 1;

  for (n=n-3; n>0; n--){
    as = abcs - as;
    abcs *= 2;
  }

  return 2*(abcs - as);
}
```

Here's why:

```
Look at one strand of the decision tree (the other one is symmetrical):

                                        A

                  B                                            C...
     A                        C
B         C               A        B
A    C    A    B          B   C    A   C
B C  A B  B C  A C        A C A B  B C A B


Num A's     Num ABC's (starting with first B on the left)
0            1
1 (1-0)      2
1 (2-1)      4
3 (4-1)      8
5 (8-3)      16
11 (16-5)    32

Cleary, we can't use the strands that end with the A's...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write a recursive brute force solution and then memoize it (aka top down dynamic programming). Recursive solutions are more intuitive and easy to come up with. Here is my version:

```python
# search space (we have triangle with nodes)
nodes = ["A", "B", "C"]

@cache  # memoize!
def recurse(length, steps):
    # if length of the path is n and the last node is "A", then it's 
    # a valid path and we can count it.
    if length == n and ((steps-1)%3 == 0 or (steps+1)%3 == 0):
        return 1
    
    # we don't want paths having len > n.
    if length > n:
        return 0
    
    # from each position, we have two possibilities, either go to next
    # node or previous node. Total paths will be sum of both the
    # possibilities. We do this recursively.
    return recurse(length+1, steps+1) + recurse(length+1, steps-1)
```